# Max number or arguments to `where ... in (...)` clause in Proc SQL?

Tags: sas, proc-sql

Suppose I'm subsetting a table and summarizing it in `proc sql`.  The code uses a `where ... in` clause and a subquery to do the subsetting.  I know that some SQL engines would set some limit on the number of arguments to the `where ... in` clause.  Does SAS has have limit on this?  This question would apply to a program like this:

```
proc sql;
    create table want as
    select
        ID,
        sum(var1) as var1,
        sum(var2) as var2,
        sum(var3) as var3
    from largetable
    where ID in (select ID from longlist)
    group by ID;
quit;
```

What if `longlist` returns 10,000 IDs?  How about 10,000,000?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of any explicit limit on this.  SAS's SQL parser seems to convert these often to JOINs, when they're not explicitly coded in the table; that means there are *some* limitations, but not particularly small ones.

I do believe there is a limit to the length of a SQL statement in total, so if you were trying to include an extremely long list in *text* you might run into problems, but in the example above I don't see a problem with 10,000,000 IDs.  I just tested it with 250,000,000 IDs in the longlist table, and SAS had no problem with it:

```
data largetable;
  do id=1 to 1e8;
    if mod(id,7)=0 then output;
  end;
run;

data ids;
  do id = 1 to 1e9;
    if mod(id,4)=0 then output;
  end;
run;

proc sql _method;
    create table want as
    select
        ID
    from largetable
    where ID in (select ID from IDs)
    group by ID;
quit;
```

Interestingly, adding _method indicates it does not do this as a join, but as a subquery.  I'm not sure why, at least in this case; everything I've been told says that it should convert this to a join implicitly.

Comment: I expect that if you connected from SAS to another rdbms it might well be auto-converted. What led you to expect SAS itself to do that?

Comment: @user667489 SAS `proc sql` is a SQL optimizer/interpreter/compiler just like any other RDBMS; SQL of any sort is a declarative language, after all, so the interpreter will do various things to optimize the query.  SAS's optimizer is not as good as SQL Server's, but it's still pretty good.  Converting a subquery `in` to a join is a very common optimization in any flavor of SQL.

Answer (score 4):

As Joe has said, there should probably be no problems with any reasonable number of rows in the `longlist` table. However, although this may be readable, [a join may perform better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-sub-query).

Do you have a strong preference for running the query as written rather than doing a left join, e.g.

```
proc sql;
    create table want as
    select
        b.ID,
        sum(b.var1) as var1,
        sum(b.var2) as var2,
        sum(b.var3) as var3
    from longlist a left join largetable b
     on a.ID = b.ID
     group by b.ID;
quit;
```

Elaborating a bit on entering a long list as text - I'm not aware of any limit on the length of any one statement in SAS, but there are [various limits](http://support.sas.com/kb/15/883.html) on the length of individual lines of code, depending on your version and how you're submitting it. I suspect it's possible to split a long statement over several lines each approaching the maximum allowed length.

Comment: No strong preference.  This question was not really about how to do something, but just to confirm this particular syntax wasn't dangerous.  Thanks for info!